# Making changes to an existing table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just had a quick question. Once you've ran a change migration like say you needed to add a column to an existing table, so you create a change migration. If I've already ran that change migration, and wanted to add a different new column in that table, can i just edit the code in the change migration to add the second new column or do i have to create a whole new change migration?

Comment: In your `schema.rb` file, the version number will change.  Since the Migration has ran successfully, it is noted in the version number and will not run it again.  

It is best that you make a new migration and make your changes.  This way it's easier to roll back any changes that you need one by one.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you ran migration already that means your change has been reflected to your database. so at this point if you want another change then its quite straight you need to make new migration, but there is a way that to make change in same migration for that

1 first you need to revert that migration that means you need to rollback that migration on which you want to change

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```

2- now make changes(`in your case add another column also`) in this migration file and run

```
rake db:migrate
```

but its always recommended to create new migration if you haven't push your code to git yet.

Answer (score 0):

To implement changes to the same migration file:

1) Go one step back using ROLLBACK

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

2) Implement the changes:

```
# add new column
```

3) Run db migrate:

```
rake db:migrate
```